# What would be the grad program for studying Paralegal in the US?

Tags: graduate-admissions

What would be the grad program for studying Paralegal in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, there isn't any standard- there are associate's, bachelor's, and master's degree programs for paralegals along with shorter certificate programs.  There are also professional certifications that you can take a test for.

If you really want a master's degree, there are lots of programs offering a "Master's in Legal Studies" for paralegals.

Comment: Thank you, so these Master's degree is designed for NON-Legal / Lawyers to do this program ???

Comment: They're not law degrees.  It wouldn't surprise me if an immigrant with legal training from another country took one of these programs and became a paralegal in the US.

Comment: Thank you Professor, very helpful